# Starting with Vue.js and nothing is displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to start using vue.js and having issue setting it up. In my package.json I installed the latest version `"vue": "^2.6.14",` and in my `main.js` folder I included like this

```js
import Vue from "vue";
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })
```

and in my html file I added this:

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

when webpack compiles, it creates this [main.js file](https://pastebin.com/raw/aJhuUgCY) but the {{ message }} is not changed to Hello Vue!. What I am doing wrong here that this is not working?

Also no error is showing in dev tools.

Comment: you may want to move data property and template=`{{message}}` to `App.vue` instead of `main.js` and `index.html`.

Comment: Check your browser's dev-tools console for errors

Comment: @Phil thanks, but no error there

Comment: You're going to have to walk through all the steps you're taking... how did you start the project? Are you using Vue CLI? What commands are you running to run or build your project? What address are you opening in your browser?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bush-elvfk?file=/src/main.js), your code works just fine

Comment: maybe my webpack configuration is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import Vue from "vue";
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        message: "Hello Vue!"
      }
    }
  }).$mount('#app');
```

This would solve your problem

Comment: where would I add this? to the end of the file?

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to replace data object to function

Answer (score -1):

```
import Vue from "vue";

new Vue({
   data() {
       return {
          message: 'Hello Vue!',
       };
   },
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: unfortunately still doesnt show anything, I also added `window.Vue = Vue;` but nothing shows up

Comment: Are you sure you are including the js file in your html..

Comment: yes, I checked the source code and main.js is loaded - the content is the one I posted in question.

Comment: Yeah bro, your not including your js file in the html. works fine. https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111